# jQuery delay gets ignored and executes siblings

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery version 1.7.1 from Google CDN and have the following code:

`$(menuInstance).delay(2000).removeClass('loading').html(ul);`

However the delay is ignored and it moves straight onto my remove class and insert HTML. Any ideas why the delay is being ignored? Thanks

Comment: Are you invoking that code inside a `$(document).ready()` block?

Comment: I think delay only applies to jquery effects like fade.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay/ : "Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue." `removeClass` also does not use the effects queue. (Don't feel bad; we've all tried to use `delay()` that way at some point.)

Comment: look at my solution qith delay and queue - no animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `.delay` like that. You need to use `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $(menuInstance).removeClass('loading').html(ul);
}, 2000);
```

`delay` can only be used for [animation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) queues.

Answer (score 3):

delay only works for methods that can be queued like animations: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

You will need to use a timeout. Our you could use http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 3):

That is not what `.delay()` does..

Check the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/delay/

**Quote**

> **Description**: Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items **in the queue**.

and

> The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

As you can see it only works with jQuery queues.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsbin.com/ohipew/edit#javascript,html

```
 $(menuInstance).delay(2000).queue(

  function (a)
  {
      $(this).removeClass('loading').html(ul)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`.delay()` is for delaying jquery visual effects.
for `.remove()` you should use `setTimeout`.

see also: 
[jQuery: append() object, remove() it with delay()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655627/jquery-append-object-remove-it-with-delay)