# Hide instance of element after 5 seconds using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, notifications

I'm trying to implement a notification style JQuery function. Here's what I have so far

```
function notify(message, type, autohide, delay) {
  message = message;
  type = type || "";
  autohide = autohide || false;
  delay = delay || 0;
  $('#notification-container').append("<div class='notice " + type + "'>" + message + "<div class='close-container'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></div></div>");
};
```

Calling this function adds the notification correctly but I haven't been able to make that specific element be removed after 'delay' period of time without removing all the other notifications. I've search but have only found #id based solutions or class based. I don't want to have to put ids on each new notification and if I remove it by .notice, all notifications will expire at the same time. The closest I've gotten has been to use

```
if (autohide) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#notification-container .notice:last-child').remove();
  }, delay);
}
```

But I'm sure all of you can see how that's flawed. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Are you seeing any errors in your console? Where is that if statement available in your main code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655627/jquery-append-object-remove-it-with-delay

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón I've already seen that question, but it removes it based on class.

Comment: then change the jquery css query, not?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy the problem with my last code block is that if I add multiple notifications quickly, it will only remove the newest notification instead of the oldest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the element a jQuery object and use that reference to remove it

```
function notify(message, type, autohide, delay) {
  message = message;
  type = type || "";
  autohide = autohide || false;
  delay = delay || 0;
  var $notification = $("<div class='notice " + type + "'>" + message + "<div class='close-container'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></div></div>");
  $('#notification-container').append($notification);


  if (autohide) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $notification.remove();    
    }, delay);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I really this answer although I'm not sure how it works. How does jquery know which $notification I'm talking about when you say $notification.remove();

Comment: Instead of appending an anonymous html string that gets converted to dom elements..you are appending a dom element that is represented by a jQuery object. The reference to object is not lost during the append

Comment: As for knowing which... there is only one scoped variable object within each instance of the function call

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer is more suited to my needs.

Comment: What @adeneo did is same concept...just written differently

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var deleteNotice = function(elem,delay){
    var tout = setTimeout(function(){
        clearTimeout(tout);
        elem.remove()
    },delay);//Now this acts on only this element
}

function notify(message, type) {
    $('#notification-container').append("<div class='notice " + type + "'>" + message + "<div class='close-container'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></div></div>");
    //Now assign this element to a variable, so everytime your function is called el represents the latest notice
    var el = $('#notification-container .notice:last-child');
    deleteNotice(el,10000);//A function to delete this selected element
};
```

Comment: Let me try this, but wouldn't this run into the issue of removing the last element from #notification-container which could be the notification that was added after?

Comment: Scoping will save you from that! The last child you are passing on to delete notice is a jquery element not the 'last child' per say.

Comment: Works! Very well done. Selecting as answer as soon as it let's me.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the elements and store them in local variables, that way only the elements for that function call would be removed. Something like

```
function notify(message, type, autohide, delay) {
    var div = $('<div />', {
        'class' : 'notice' + (type ? ' '+type : ''),
        text    : message || ''
    }),
        close = $('<div />', {
            'class' : 'close-container',
            on      : {
                click : function() {
                    div.remove();
                }
            },
            html : $('<span />', {
                'class' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'
            })
    });

    if (autohide) {
        div.delay(delay||0).hide(0, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }

    $('#notification-container').append(div.append(close));
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/u0x5pfst/)

[Here's a version that supports animations](https://jsfiddle.net/u0x5pfst/1/)

Comment: I've never seen the way you're creating the divs before. Do you know of a good resource where I could read up on that? Or even just what it's called?

Comment: @WiseOlMan - Sure, it's in the [**jQuery documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#entry-examples-1), and is the preferred way of creating an element.