# jQuery : snackbar : append() element,add css by class and then remove() it with delay

Tags: jquery

I created a form with several inputs, one of them is "Full Name",and of course a submit button at the end.

function checks if the name input is alphabetical characters only,
if true, it will append the div element , add the css class, 
snackbar will fade in and out, and finally disappear.
what is wrong with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".submitForm").click(function(){
    var fullname = $("#firstName").value; 
    var checkIfTrue = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/.test(fullname);
    if (checkIfTrue==true) {
        $('body').append("<div id='textBox'> some text</div>"); 
        $("#textBox").addClass("showPopup");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#textBox").remove();}, 3000); 
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        alert("wrong input");
        return false;
    }   
})
})
```

and there is the relevant css:

```
.showPopup {
  visibility : visible;
  animation : fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {bottom: 20px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 20px; opacity: 1;}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

cheers
(couldn't figure it out myself with :
[jQuery: append() object, remove() it with delay()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655627/jquery-append-object-remove-it-with-delay) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some minor issues like the use of `.value` (vanilla JS) instead of `.val()` (jQuery)...

And certainly the major issue, the submit prevention on button click. See [`.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

For the rest, see comments within code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".submitForm").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();  // Prevent the submit behavior of the button

    var fullname = $("#firstName").val(); // .val() instead of .value
    var checkIfTrue = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/.test(fullname);
    if (checkIfTrue) {  // No need for the ==true
      $('body').append("<div id='textBox'> some text</div>"); 
      $("#textBox").addClass("showPopup");
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#textBox").remove();
        $(this).closest("form").submit();  // Since it's ok and the animation's over... Submit the form.
      }, 3000); 
      //return true;  // No need to return anything from an event handler
    } 
    else {
      alert("wrong input");
      //return false;  // No need to return anything from an event handler
    }   
  })
})
```